# multi-column, editable TreeView in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

Yeah I am looking for some C# code of a multi-column TreeView where each cell can be inline-edited and also dragging the rows is supported.

Do you have any good examples of such a custom component?

Comment: Did you able to find such TreeView control. I am looking for the same TreeView control with multi-column and editable. Please provide reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the TreeListView example, that gives you a good intro into the GridViewRowPresenter that can be used in this scenario.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771523.aspx

This gives you multi-column and editing can easily be done with databindings in the template.

For D&D you have to look somewhere else. But probably this blog entry of Bea Costa you can adapt to you're needs http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53.

hth,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

[SharpDevelop](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/RoadmapVersion4x.ashx) has a TreeViewEx that supports multi-column, etc...

Comment: Can I use that TreeViewEx also in Visual Studio somehow?